# Error at charCodeAt, after Nodejs update

Tags: node.js, updates, passport.js

So ive been developing my app on node 0.8.20 and been using passport for google authentication.

I updated my node to latest version 0.10 and i get an error

```
_modules\passport-openid\node_modules\openid\lib\convert.js:33
  if(i.charCodeAt(0) > 127)
       ^
TypeError: Object n++n++:?n++9rn++??n++n+++ón++1??7q~n++n++qn++v#s?fn++?n++Z.'n+
 has no method 'charCodeAt'
```

I have updated to latest version of passport and passport-google modules, and it dosent seem to help.

Also there is no issues raised on passport community regarding this. So i think its something to do with my code.

**Update:**
    Ok seem like this error is not specific to node 0.10. It exists from [0.9](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/80) . Suggested work around is to move to google oauth. No solution yet

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the crypto module in node returns buffer objects instead of binary strings as default since version 0.9.0.

This diff will fix the problem:

```
diff --git node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js
index 1431dd7..798f741 100644
--- node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js
+++ node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js
@@ -634,9 +634,9 @@ openid.associate = function(provider, callback, strict, algorithm)
   if(algorithm.indexOf('no-encryption') === -1)
   {
     dh = _createDiffieHellmanKeyExchange(algorithm);
-    params['openid.dh_modulus'] = _toBase64(dh.getPrime());
-    params['openid.dh_gen'] = _toBase64(dh.getGenerator());
-    params['openid.dh_consumer_public'] = _toBase64(dh.getPublicKey());
+    params['openid.dh_modulus'] = _toBase64(dh.getPrime("binary"));
+    params['openid.dh_gen'] = _toBase64(dh.getGenerator("binary"));
+    params['openid.dh_consumer_public'] = _toBase64(dh.getPublicKey("binary"));
   }

   _post(provider.endpoint, params, function(data, headers, statusCode)
@@ -713,10 +713,10 @@ openid.associate = function(provider, callback, strict, algorithm)
       else
       {
         var serverPublic = _fromBase64(data.dh_server_public);
-        var sharedSecret = convert.btwoc(dh.computeSecret(serverPublic));
+        var sharedSecret = convert.btwoc(dh.computeSecret(serverPublic, "binary", "binary"));
         var hash = crypto.createHash(hashAlgorithm);
         hash.update(sharedSecret);
-        sharedSecret = hash.digest();
+        sharedSecret = hash.digest("binary");
         var encMacKey = convert.base64.decode(data.enc_mac_key);
         secret = convert.base64.encode(_xor(encMacKey, sharedSecret));
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oki, So this error dosent seem to have fixed. But found a workaround, which can work with the existing code under passport-google module

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/tree/master/examples/oauth2

Issue had been [raised](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/issues/4) in passport github. But they have closed pointing to workaround rather than fix